# AWS Lambda Function to Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-fargate, aws-sam

I have a deployed AWS Lambda function that I would like to run in a container. There are no restrictions on where this container is run (AWS Fargate, EC2, My Local Machine, etc. are perfect) There are no restrictions on which containerization software is used, though docker is preferred.

I have access to everything about the lambda function returned from [this Lambda API function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetFunction.html). I do not have access to the raw code.

I looked into AWS SAM, though it appears that i need a copy of the raw code in order to create a container.

Is this possible to do? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Lambda functions on AWS run only inside containers. You don't have access (or need to have access) to the underlying resources or container technology it uses. 

AWS SAM is just a wrapper for AWS CloudFormation which allows you to create stacks in a more simplified manner.

Comment: The `GetFunction` API you mentioned provides you with a link where you can download the deployment package -- a zip file of the "raw code."